# Bootstrapping data on server starts in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel app, I need to add logic which called only once the server starts (i.e. bootstrapping data, preload cache). I've already tried injecting code in start.php, but it is being called on every client request.

As a workaround, I am using an artisan custom command to do so, but I want to automate the logic on every deployment to the apache server.

Comment: Why don't you call your artisan command as part of your deployment script?

Comment: @JofryHS that's one way to do it, but I am wondering too if there is such a thing supported by Laravel.

Comment: AFAIK, deployment methods is not available in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen done before is set up a file similar to how WP / Laravel handle maintenance mode by generating a placeholder file,  if the file exists it puts the site into maintenance mode, you could do the same for your deployment, create a dummy file, and when your bootstraps scripts run, have it unlink() / destroy the file, then just check if file_exists() to run the bootstrap data.  If the file doesn't exist it assumes the bootstrap has run and never executes until you deploy again in that case it would push up the dummy file again.